# bootstrap modal with knockout js binding doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal binded with knockout js, but each time I try to load the modal it says `self.showmodalmoreborrowinfo is not a function`, so its confusing me why its not working.

Here is the code in the js file
Opening the modal here through initializing it

```
self.InitializeRegister = function(){
            if(self.openmodel() == 1){
                self.showmodalmoreborrowinfo();
            }
            self.showmodalmoreborrowinfo();
        }
        self.InitializeRegister();
```

This code is at the end of the js for the databinding

```
// Custom binding handler for modal dialog.
    (function ($) {

        ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapShowModal = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                $(element).modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: false });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
                    $(element).modal('show');
                    // this is to focus input field inside dialog
                    // $("input", element).focus();
                }
                else {
                    $(element).modal('hide');
                }
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

And here is the html

```
<div data-bind="bootstrapShowModal: modalmoreborrowinfo" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="text-center">
                <H1>We need a bit more information for you to apply for borrowing</H1>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="salary" data-bind="value: borrowersalary" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Salary">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="job" data-bind="value: borrowerjob" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Job">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="housing" data-bind="value: borrowerhousing" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Housing? eg Permanent">
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

other functions knockout js functions are working, just this one isnt.

Comment: hard to tell without the context of `self`

Comment: `modalmoreborrowinfo` should be an `observable`. I don't see your `showmodalmoreborrowinfo` function, but you don't really need it. Showing the modal is done by setting the observable to `true`, triggering the binding update: `self.showmodalmoreborrowinfo(true)`. Setting it to false should hide it: `showmodalmoreborrowinfo(false)`. Show more of your view model if you need a definite answer.